# How to handle Datatable Compute exception properly?

Tags: c#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Compute(items.Value.ToString(), null);
```

How to handle above exception properly if there is some error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: items is not defined in your code snippet. What is it?

Comment: it is a string of equation like 2+2*5

Comment: I believe 2 + 2 * 5 is an integer or nullable integer expression instead. Usage of `Value` property suggests it is a nullable value type expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can avoid the run-time null reference exception for nullable value types by checking its `HasValue` property:

```
int? items = 2 + 2 * 5;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Compute(items.HasValue ? items.Value.ToString() : "" , null);
```